# Operator-assigned list of lists can't reference specific list element

Tags: python

I'm setting up a two-dimensional matrix that begins with identical lines.  When I create a list of lists using a lines=n*[list(string)] to create n lists of identical character lists, it seems to work.  But when I try to assign a specific value to an element in a row, it is copied in all rows.

I did the following in Jupyter Notebook.  Code and output are shown.  I also printed the id() of the specific elements in the matrix while trying to figure out what's going on.  If I set up the matrix with a multiplication, all rows seem to be at the same address.  And making an assignment to an element changes all rows.  When I hard code the list, the elements start with the same address, but when I make an assignment, the address changes.

Is Python really supposed to work like this?

Here's what doesn't work...

```
lines=11*[list('   |   |   ')] # Initialize matrix a list of lists
lines[0][0]='0'

for i in lines: print(i)
print('address of 0,0: '+str(id(lines[0][0])))
print('address of 1,0: '+str(id(lines[1][0])))
print('address of 2,0: '+str(id(lines[2][0])))
```

output...

```
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
address of 0,0: 2043952387048
address of 1,0: 2043952387048
address of 2,0: 2043952387048
```

Here's what works...

```
lines=[[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '], # Initialize matrix with data.
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

lines[0][0]='0'

for i in lines: print(i)
print('address of 0,0: '+str(id(lines[0][0])))
print('address of 1,0: '+str(id(lines[1][0])))
print('address of 2,0: '+str(id(lines[2][0])))
```

output...

```
['0', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ']
address of 0,0: 2043952387048
address of 1,0: 2043951596632
address of 2,0: 2043951596632
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
lines=11*[list('   |   |   ')]
```

you're only calling `list('   |   |   ')` once. It makes one list, and that same list is referenced 11 times. It's equivalent to:

```
temp = list('   |   |   ')
lines = 11*[temp]
```

There's only one `temp` list, this creates a list with 11 references to that list. Multiplying a list only duplicates the outer structure of the container, it doesn't make copies of the objects that it refers to.

Use:

```
lines = [list('   |   |   ') for _ in range(11)]
```

so it will call `list()` 11 times, each creating a new list.

Comment: one too many [ in your answer but the concept works perfectly!

Comment: I'm really sorry for dwelling on this and am hoping to understand what the compiler is doing.  Should it really work this way, and where in the docs is there something that might explain this?

It seems like the compiler is letting me create what looks like a list of lists, but then it treats it like a single list.  What is the utility in these operations?

The simplest example is:

l=[0,1,2,3,4,5]; 
    l2=[l]+[l];
    l2[0][0]=9;
    print(l2);

Sure looks like a mutable list, bit isn't.  And nothing warns about this.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show more clearly how this works.

Answer (score 0):

This problem really haunted me, and I finally found the answer in the docs.  The docs even said, "This often haunts new Python programmers;..."  How it works is written here, https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common

This "feature" is fully described in Note 2 that goes with the "s * n or n * s" table entry.

However, I think there is an omission in the docs regarding the "s + t" table entry.  Notes 6 & 7 apply to this.  Maybe a note similar to 2 needs to be added?  The reason is because you get the same behavior when you run the following code...

```
s=[[1,2,3]]
s = s + s
s[0][0]=4
print(s)
```

The output is, "[[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]".

This one didn't haunt me so much, because I was expecting it.

Comment: More about this here... [link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/faq/programming.html#faq-multidimensional-list)